# Entity Framework An Exception was thrown while running the transformation code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, wcf

I keep getting this error when I add a Entity Data Model to project, which basically is creating a modal for a .mdf file in App_Data folder. It's a WCF project.

I am using VS 2015 community edition and also have Xamarin installed.

I tried to change the .net framework version from 4.5.0 to 4.5.1-2 and 4.6.1, but I keep getting this error. I also installed manually Microsoft.CodeAnalysis package. Tried deleting every thing from packages folder and then restored all the nuget plugin. But everything thing is a fail for me.

Reference to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is added and its versions is "1.3.1.0"

What I might be doing wrong here?

Error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error       An Exception was thrown while running the transformation code. The process cannot continue.  The following Exception was thrown:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>       File name: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge..ctor(String source, Boolean debug, IEnumerable`1 references, String cmdLineArguments)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Create(SupportedLanguage language, String source, Boolean debug, IEnumerable`1 references, String cmdLineArguments)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.LocateAssembly(Boolean cacheAssemblies, String fullClassName, String source, String inputFile, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, IEnumerable`1 compilerReferences, String compilerOptions)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PrepareTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host)
>       === Pre-bind state information ===
>       LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>        (Fully-specified)
>       LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/
>       LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>       Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>       ===
>       LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>       LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Hitin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\devenv.exe.config
>       LOG: Using host configuration file: 
>       LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>       LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80131040.            1

Comment: did you restart the machine after update ?

Comment: @Sampath I just restarted it, and the error still exists, so it must be something else I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It's sorted now, looks like xamarin update (may) have corrupted the VS 2015 installation.

Repair doesn't work here.

So the only solution was to upgrade from "VS2015 Community update 2" to "VS2015 Community update 3" , and now both xamarin as well as VS is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer on developercommunity.visualstudio.com from avatar Kees Alderliesten, maybe it would help for you

`as a workaround, you could try to copy both files to \windows\system32 and rename them to $(VSAPPIDDIR)EntityFramework.dll and $(VSAPPIDDIR)Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll (yes, Windows accepts that). It got it working again that way.`